# Protractor element not visible input field

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor, automated-tests

Hi my issue is that i keep getting message, "element not visible" in protractor. I simply want it to find the input field and sendKeys to it and it is not working. This whole project site is done in angualrJS I even have     browser.ignoreSynchronization = true; set. Any suggestions.

HTML Code

```
input parse-search-query="" type="text" tabindex="1" name="search_query" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Search by City ST, Zip, or Address" data-ng-model="searchQueryFieldCtrl.searchFormController.searchParams.search_query" data-ng-change="searchQueryFieldCtrl.searchFormController.clearErrors()" data-focus-on="focusQuery || form.search_query.$error" data-uib-typeahead="suggestion as suggestion.label for suggestion in searchQueryFieldCtrl.getSuggestions($viewValue)" data-typeahead-focus-first="false" data-typeahead-min-length="0" data-typeahead-wait-ms="300" data-typeahead-on-select="searchQueryFieldCtrl.setSearch($item)" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-scope" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-expanded="false" aria-owns="typeahead-69-869">
```

**spec.js**

```
describe('New stack hompage test', function() {
  it('should test search form', function() {

    browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;


  var flow = protractor.promise.controlFlow();
  function waitOne() {
    return protractor.promise.delayed(3000);
  }

  function sleep() {
    flow.execute(waitOne);

  }
        browser.get('http://localhost:3000/');
        sleep() 

        expect(browser.getTitle()).toEqual('Find Homes for Sale, Rent & Real Estate Listings Nationwide at Homes.com');
        sleep() 

        var search = element.all(by.css("input[name='search_query']"));
        sleep()
        search.sendKeys('anything'); // this is not working
  });
});
```

Comment: if it's an angular app, why are you setting `ignoreSynchronization = true`?

Comment: i get synchronization errors

Comment: Did you try extending the timeouts?  Most timeouts are 10 seconds by default, which is very low in my opinion.  [timeout reference](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/timeouts.md)

Comment: Yes extended it 22 many people have had the same issue on stack overflow and had to set it to (true).

Comment: element.all return Array of Elements so use array index number e.g.
**search[0].sendKeys('anything');**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use protractor.ExpectedConditions to check whether an element visible or not before going to send input to it. You can follow the below code:

```
var EC=protractor.ExpectedConditions;

 describe('New stack hompage test', function() {
    beforeEach(function(){
       browser.get('http://localhost:3000/');
     });
    it('should test search form', function() {
      var search =  
              element.all(by.css("input[name='search_query']")).first();
      expect(browser.getTitle()).toEqual('Find Homes for Sale, Rent & Real 
                                Estate Listings Nationwide at Homes.com');
      browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(search).call(),8000,'search filed not 
                                                          visible');
      search.sendKeys('anything');
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you explain what the .call() does in this case?

Comment: @user2020347 It is for handling promises of EC.visibilityOf(ele)

Comment: I get this message from protractor: Failed: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined.

Comment: Also are you saying that even though this is an input box for me to type in i may not be able sendkeys to it?

Comment: @JonathanHofler. Does multiple elements has same locator -  input[name='search_query']"  ?

Comment: You write element.all() right , so i thought there would many elements with same locators, Any try it now, i have update code

Comment: I tried that code and i get message now saying:   Failed: Index out of bound. Trying to access element at index: 0, but there are only 0 elements that match locator By(css selector, input[name='search_query'])

Comment: Change locator now, var search = element(by.css('[data-ng-model="searchQueryFieldCtrl.searchFormController.searchParams.search_query"]'));

Comment: Okay I will do it and let u know an hour I'm in a meeting at work. Thanks so much for ur help I will get back with u asap. Is there s way to contact u through chat.

Comment: yup, through skype - sallojusuresh

Comment: okay changed it to this       var search = element(by.css('[data-ng-model="searchQueryFieldCtrl.searchF‌​ormController.search‌​Params.search_query"‌​]') taking the .first() out and got message

Comment: Failed: invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified